# Mageplaza SMTP: 5.7.9 Application-specific password required

Tags: magento2, smtp, mageplaza

After install Mageplaza SMTP on Magento 2.3.3 i got this issue. Please help.

```
5.7.9 Application-specific password required. 
Learn more at 5.7.9 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=InvalidSecondFactor m3sm778013pjs.22 - gsmtp
```

[image]

Comment: Let me know if still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mageplaza update solution for that. You can see this below video link.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndxUgivCszE

Reference : https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-smtp/issues/181

Hope it may be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, its worked.